# Visual Studio build application to run from cd

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a solution in which i play video from a specified directory. When i build my application, the directory of videos is in the debug folder along with the executable file. I can easily run my exe file from there but however when i copy that executable file and the directory from the debug folder into somewhere on desktop, i simply get that "the application has stopped working". I am stuck. Is there a way to build everthing i have in my project into just one executable file so that when i run it, it should just run without setup. Actually i am making this application portable to be run from cd.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what do you want? To be able to move the executable or not?

Comment: yea i want to move it and burn it on a cd.